# How to stop Â from being generated before currency?

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a POS GUI system and have had no trouble with using any currency symbols in the program so far. When I brought another file of code across into my main class for my GUI, I now suddenly have the symbol Â appearing before the '£' symbol I have.

I've tried changing the original files encoding to make sure its in UTF-8, then copy it over, but it still appears.

This is an example of the generating I'm doing for each component in the code:

```
btnSubTwoOptionOne.setSize(135,50);
btnSubTwoOptionOne.addActionListener(this);
btnSubTwoOptionOne.setBackground( new Color(-10027162) );
btnSubTwoOptionOne.setText("Meat Pie £2.20");
panelMainSubTwo.add(btnSubTwoOptionOne);
```

Hope someone can help me with this. :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It should show how the additional character is shown in the GUI.

Answer (score 4):

The problem seems to be that the source file *is* in UTF-8, but you're compiling the code using windows-1252.

The `£` ([Unicode Character 'POUND SIGN' (U+00A3)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a3/index.htm)) is encoded in UTF-8 as `C2 A3`. If you decode those two bytes in [windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set), you get `Â` (`C2`) and `£` (`A3`).